# Sharing global variables SASS - vue

Tags: webpack, vue.js, sass, vue-loader

I'm developing a project in vue, and in some components my idea was to use single file components.

I followed the documentation of the [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass) in order to use SASS in the components.

And it worked, the problem is that now I wanted to add the file with the SASS variables and I'm not getting it.

I saw on some sides to import this file into each of the components, but I thought it was not the best solution, so I continued the search and found some people talking the way I would represent in the code, but it still does not work.

Any suggestion.

webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            data: '@import "/resources/assets/sass/_variables.scss";'
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

component vue

```
<template>
     <div class="test">
         <span>test</span>
     </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
    .test {
        background: $red;
    }
</style>
```

error

```
Undefined variable: "$red".
```

Answer (score 1):

What's up?
I was having the same problem. Try to comment the `css-loader` and the `vue-style-loader`.

### Will be it a problem in the future?

So, as I can see you're even not using both of these libraries. So... no.
But, if you want to keep it on your project, make sure that `vue-style-loader` and `css-loader` are correctly installed at your **package.json**.

#### To install them:

1. `npm install -D vue-style-loader`
2. `npm install -D css-loader`

*But I personally think it's better just not using it...*

## Your code will be like:

```
    module: {
            rules: [
              // ... other rules omitted
       
              {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                //   'vue-style-loader',
                //   'postcss-loader',
                  {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                      // you can also read from a file, e.g. `variables.scss`
                      // use `prependData` here if sass-loader version = 8, or
                      // `data` if sass-loader version < 8
                      additionalData: `@import "path/to/your/file.scss";`
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
```

I hope it becomes helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
options: {
  resources: [
   path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/sass/_variables.scss')
  ]
}
```

so it would be like this:

```
module.exports = {
        module: {
            rules:[
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    use: 'vue-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                             resources: [
                              path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/sass/_variables.scss')
                             ]
                            },
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

Comment: I tried to use the example you have in the vue-loder documentation `data: '$color: red;'` and it also did not work.